# How to manage number values with points?

Tags: php

$val represents  1,949.58 from my sql

```
 $sold = 50;
    if ($val>$sold){
    echo "true";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "false";
    }
```

I get false. somehow 50 is bigger than 1,949.58 and this because of the ',' sign. I need some advices on how to manage this right. Thx

Comment: BTW, how did you store your $val values in the DB? I mean what data type?

Comment: @MarCejas: if it has the comma in it when he retrieves it, then it's one of the string types (varchar/char).

Comment: @ChrisLively yeah, i know. I just double check, and why he stored numbers in varchar? It is also advisble to store those in double.

Comment: @MarCejas: That is a very good question, and yes, it should be stored as a double.  Preferably with 4 places per GAAP requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$val` is interpreted by php to be a string.  When doing the comparison, it's doing a string compare so you aren't going to get the results you expect.

You need to force them to be a floating point type.  Look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php  Specifically the comments on that function.

Something like this *should* work:

```
function floatvalue($value) { 
     return floatval(preg_replace('#^([-]*[0-9\.,\' ]+?)((\.|,){1}([0-9-]{1,2}))*$#e', "str_replace(array('.', ',', \"'\", ' '), '', '\\1') . '.\\4'", $value)); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert these values to floats instead of strings. Right now you're doing string comparisons and not numerical comparisons. The following converts those strings to floating values.

```
$val = parseFloat('1,949.58'.replace(/\,/g,""))
$sold = parseFloat('50')
```

The .replace removes the "," from your original string before it's parsed to a Float.